# ReactJS rxjs obervable dom ajax, get request treated as an option method

Tags: ajax, reactjs, http, redux, rxjs

I am using 2 seperate libraries to make an http get in my reactjs application as follows

```
            import { ajax } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/ajax';
            import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
            import * as actionType from '../types';
            import types from '../types';

            export default (action$, store) => {
                return action$.ofType(types.getIssuers.requested).mergeMap(action => {
                    return ajax({
                        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8181/api/v1/status',
                        responseType: 'json',
                        method: 'GET',
                        timeout: 2000
                    }).map(xhr => {
                        console.log("Issuer Epic")
                        const jsonBody = xhr.response;
                        return {
                            type: types.getIssuers.completed,
                            payload: jsonBody,
                        };
                    }).catch(error => {
                        return Observable.of({ type: actionType.LOAD_CUSTOMER_ERROR });
                    });
                });
            };




            var request = require('request');
            request('http://127.0.0.1:8181/api/v1/status', function (error, response, body) {
              console.log('error:', error);  
              console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
              console.log('body:', body);
            });
```

I can retrieve data without an issue if um using request library

I need to use `rxjs/observable/dom/ajax` as per the project requirement but it seems my `HTTP GET` request turned out to be an `HTTP OPTION`. Is there a fix for this ?

Comment: If you see just the `OPTION` method it seems to be CORS issue.

Comment: CORS configuration was fine and it works with request library @martin